# How can I create a custom Manager to return the union of other Managers

Tags: django

I have the following django models:

```
class Video(models.Model):

    # ... snip ...

    # Entities detected using face tracking                                                                                                                                                                  
    faces = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, related_name="facevids", blank=True)
    # Entities detected using speaker diarisation                                                                                                                                                            
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, related_name="speakervids", blank=True)
    # Entities detected by extracting names from metadata and ocr                                                                                                                                            
    names = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, related_name="namevids", blank=True)
    # Entities detected using logo detection                                                                                                                                                                 
    logos = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, related_name="logovids", blank=True)

class Entity(models.Model):

    entity_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 100)
```

I want to add a custom Manager to `Entity` so that I can access an `allvids` ManyToMany custom field in the same manner as `facevids` or `speakervids`.

So far I've worked out how to access and union the querysets doing something like this

```
@property
def allvids(self):
    return (self.facevids.get_query_set() | self.speakervids.get_query_set() |
            self.namevids.get_query_set() | self.logovids.get_query_set()).distinct()
```

But this returns a queryset object and not a Manager, which means that access to `allvids` is not the same as `facevids`, `speakervids`, etc. I'd prefer that the end user not need to know about the implementation and access `allvids` exactly the same as the other Manager fields.